# Image style, reuse image in field collection item

Tags: 7, media, entities

I've got some problems with the image styles, when reusing an image in a field collection, because the new size of the former uploaded image is not generated altough the path to the imagefile is shown in the right way.

Uploading a new image within the field collection, everything works fine and the image shows up. Only reusing an already uploaded images crashes and only within the field collection, reusing images in other fields works fine.

Anyone may has the same problem and an idea, how to solve this?