# How to pre-generate image styles after image is uploaded

Tags: media

Is there  a quick way in Drupal 7 to generate image styles straight after the image is added to the image field?

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/54581/force-image-style-generation-on-save-node

Comment: I saw it before but was not sure it was here. It will be great if there was an option to extend image style with an option that will allow to pre-generate it. I don't want to change code for each new image style.

Answer (score 2):

You can look into [Image Style Pregenerate](http://drupal.org/project/ispreg) module to generate images.