# image_style_create_derivative not resizing the image

Tags: media

I am using `image_style_create_derivative` to create image styles on fly. Before that I am using image_style_path which creates style path.

```
$derivative_uri = image_style_path([style_name], [source]);
image_style_create_derivative([style_name], [source], $derivative_uri)
```

It generates image. Which is fine. But it is generating image with original size. Not with the size of style_name.

For example if style name is thumbnail, the generated image style size should be 160x100.

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image_style_create_derivative needs the style passed as array..,
so _ first you need to load the style or fake the array

> applying all image effects defined in $style['effects']

see: [image_style_create_derivative](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_style_create_derivative/7)

i usually use image_style_url like this (if taken from field), otherwise just pass the source.

```
        $field = field_view_field('node', $node, $field_name, reset($image), $arr_display);
        if ($img_style) {
          $uri = image_style_url($img_style, $field[0]['#item']['uri']);
        }
        else {
          $uri = file_create_url($field[0]['#item']['uri']);
        }
```